# How do I override the Xamarin Forms TabbedPage item fonts for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Wanting to achieve a consistent look for my Xamarin Forms app, I need to know how to change the font for the tabbed page tab bar icons. Using `UITabBarItem.Appearance` as the iOS API would suggest does not appear to have any effect. What's necessary to do this?

Answer (score 3):

U need to write a custom renderer like this one , take a clue from below code ! it has what u r seeking

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedTabbedPage), typeof(TabbedPageCustom))]
    namespace App.iOS
    {
        public class TabbedPageCustom : TabbedRenderer
        {
            public TabbedPageCustom ()
        {
            TabBar.TintColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
            TabBar.BarTintColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Red;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            // Set Text Font for unselected tab states
            UITextAttributes normalTextAttributes = new UITextAttributes();
            normalTextAttributes.Font = UIFont.FromName("ChalkboardSE-Light", 20.0F); // unselected
            normalTextAttributes.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

            UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
        }
        public override UIViewController SelectedViewController {
            get {
                UITextAttributes selectedTextAttributes = new UITextAttributes();
                selectedTextAttributes.Font = UIFont.FromName("ChalkboardSE-Bold", 20.0F); // SELECTED
                if (base.SelectedViewController != null)
                {
                    base.SelectedViewController.TabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(selectedTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
                }
                return base.SelectedViewController;
            }
            set {
                base.SelectedViewController = value;

                foreach (UIViewController viewController in base.ViewControllers)
                {
                    UITextAttributes normalTextAttributes = new UITextAttributes();
                    normalTextAttributes.Font = UIFont.FromName("ChalkboardSE-Light", 20.0F); // unselected
                    normalTextAttributes.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;
                    viewController.TabBarItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I indicated in the answer component of this Q&A post, just setting `UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes` wasn't doing the job for whatever reason. That setting wasn't being respected by Xamarin Forms.

Comment: what  code i gave you is working on ios9 ,  ! its perfectly respecting for me,if u want i can show u screen shot .

Answer (score 2):

This was a particularly interesting problem. I tried:

#### UITabBarItem.Appearance

Using the `UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes` method to update the UITextAttribute to my font (size 9.0f) for `UIControlState.Normal`. This didn't appear to make any difference.

#### UINavigationBar.Appearance

I found out that setting `UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes` would update both the `UINavigationBar` text appearance as well as the `UITabBarItem` text appearance.

Which was a problem because the tabbed page item font size was far too large.

#### Customizing the `TabbedRenderer`

Inspired by a sample I saw somewhere, I subclassed `TabbedRenderer` in the iOS project.

I tried overriding the settor for `TabbedRenderer.SelectedViewController` property and loop through the `ViewControllers` property to set their items. The icons would display with the standard font, but once the user changed the tab they would all update to the desired font. Almost there!

I then tried overriding `AddChildViewController` and updating that controller's `TabBarItem` after it was added which ended up having no effect. The `TabBarItem` for the added page was being updated at some point after the controller was added.

Eventually I found out that overriding `ViewWillAppear` and setting the appearance for all the tab bar items at that time seemed to do the job I desired.

I've included a sample in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/richseviora/ab10fd29e191ef1cad74cfa6064074f5).